# Partial matching of a key using a std::map

Tags: c++, stdmap

I have a question regarding how to do a partial match of a struct key using a std::map object when you are matching across two different members of that struct.

Let's start with a simple scenario.  Let's say I want to do a partial match for a key, only involving one member of the struct. I have the following map and key:

```
std::map<SimpleIdentifier, Contents>
```

The SimpleIdentifier is described below.

```
/**
 * \class SimpleIdentifier
 * \brief Used to identify and sort data in the map
 */
class SimpleIdentifier
{
public:
    SimpleIdentifier():
        idA(-1),
        idB(-1),
        partialMatch1(false) {}

    SimpleIdentifier(const long long int& a, const long long int& b):
        idA(a),
        idB(b),
        partialMatch1(false) {}

    void setPartialMatch1() { partialMatch1 = true; }

    bool operator==(const Identifier& rhs) const
    {
        return (idA == rhs.idA) && (idB == rhs.idB);
    }

    bool operator<(const Identifier& rhs) const
    {
        if (partialMatch1 || rhs.partialMatch1)
        {
            // Match A to A
            if(rhs.partialMatch1)
            {
                if(idA < rhs.idA)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else if(partialMatch1)
            {
                if(idA < rhs.idA)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            if(idA < rhs.idA)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else if (idA == rhs.idA)
            {
                if(idB < rhs.idB)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

        }

        return false;
    }

private:
    long long int idA;
    long long int idB;

    bool partialMatch1;
};
```

This lets me sort on A, and if A is equal, then sorts on B.  Thus if I have the following data

```
dataMap:

Key: [ 0, 0 ] Value: []
Key: [ 0, 1 ] Value: []
Key: [ 0, 2 ] Value: []
Key: [ 3, 1 ] Value: []
Key: [ 3, 2 ] Value: []
Key: [ 3, 3 ] Value: []
Key: [ 5, 3 ] Value: []
Key: [ 5, 7 ] Value: []
```

I can find the key-value pair corresponding to [ 3, 2 ]

```
Identifier perfectMatchID(3, 2);
std::map<SimpleIdentifier, Contents>::iterator it = dataMap.begin();
it = dataMap.find(perfectMatchID);
```

I can also find a partial match corresponding to [ 3, * ]

```
Identifier partialMatchID(3, 2);
partialMatchID.setPartialMatch1();
std::map<SimpleIdentifier, Contents>::iterator it = dataMap.begin();
it = dataMap.find(partialMatchID);
```

This is nice because I can go through each iterator in a while loop to find every matching key-value pair and do something with it.

I now want to extend it to be able to match to either member of the key matching 3, so that includes [ 3, * ] or [ *, 3 ]. SimpleIdentifier has been extended to a new objected called Identifier.

```
/**
 * \class Identifier
 * \brief Used to identify and sort data in the map
 */
class Identifier
{
public:
    Identifier():
        idA(-1),
        idB(-1),
        partialMatch(false),
        partialMatch1(false),
        partialMatch2(false),
        partialMatch3(false),
        partialMatch4(false) {}

    Identifier(const long long int& a, const long long int& b):
        idA(a),
        idB(b),
        partialMatch(false),
        partialMatch1(false),
        partialMatch2(false),
        partialMatch3(false),
        partialMatch4(false) {}

    void setPartialMatch() { partialMatch = true; }
    void setPartialMatch1() { partialMatch1 = true; }
    void setPartialMatch2() { partialMatch2 = true; }
    void setPartialMatch3() { partialMatch3 = true; }
    void setPartialMatch4() { partialMatch4 = true; }

    bool operator==(const Identifier& rhs) const
    {
        return (idA == rhs.idA) && (idB == rhs.idB);
    }

    bool operator<(const Identifier& rhs) const
    {
        if (partialMatch || rhs.partialMatch)
        {
            // In order to match, only 1 should be false, the other 3 may or may not be false
            //
            // Note: The issue here is that the check that validates for the rhs.partialMatch should be identical
            //       to the check that validates for partialMatch. Since this is const that may not be possible
            if(rhs.partialMatch)
            {
                unsigned int check1 = (idA < rhs.idA) ? 1 : 0; // Match A to A
                unsigned int check2 = (idB < rhs.idB) ? 1 : 0; // Match B to B
                unsigned int check3 = (idA < rhs.idB) ? 1 : 0; // Match A to B
                unsigned int check4 = (idB < rhs.idA) ? 1 : 0; // Match B to A

                if( (check1 + check2 + check3 + check4) > 0 )
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else if(partialMatch)
            {
                unsigned int check1 = (idA < rhs.idA) ? 1 : 0; // Match A to A
                unsigned int check2 = (idB < rhs.idB) ? 1 : 0; // Match B to B
                unsigned int check3 = (idB < rhs.idA) ? 1 : 0; // Match B to A
                unsigned int check4 = (idA < rhs.idB) ? 1 : 0; // Match A to B

                if( (check1 + check2 + check3 + check4) > 0 )
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
        else if (partialMatch1 || rhs.partialMatch1)
        {
            // Match A to A
            if(rhs.partialMatch1)
            {
                if(idA < rhs.idA)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else if(partialMatch1)
            {
                if(idA < rhs.idA)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
        else if (partialMatch2 || rhs.partialMatch2)
        {
            // Match B to B
            if(rhs.partialMatch2)
            {
                if(idB < rhs.idB)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else if(partialMatch2)
            {
                if(idB < rhs.idB)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
        else if (partialMatch3 || rhs.partialMatch3)
        {
            // Match A to B
            if(rhs.partialMatch3)
            {
                if(idA < rhs.idB)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else if(partialMatch3)
            {
                if(idB < rhs.idA)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
        else if (partialMatch4 || rhs.partialMatch4)
        {
            // Match B to A
            if(rhs.partialMatch4)
            {
                if(idB < rhs.idA)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else if(partialMatch4)
            {
                if(idA < rhs.idB)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            if(idA < rhs.idA)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else if (idA == rhs.idA)
            {
                if(idB < rhs.idB)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

        }

        return false;
    }

private:
    long long int idA;
    long long int idB;

    bool partialMatch;
    bool partialMatch1;
    bool partialMatch2;
    bool partialMatch3;
    bool partialMatch4;
};
```

Identifier lets me do partial matching, looking for the four scenarios using a  query Key. It looks for the four scenarios (not actual code)

```
queryKey.idA == idA
queryKey.idB == idB
queryKey.idA == idB
queryKey.idB == idA
```

However, in practice I need to do a while loop on each scenario only setting one of the partial matches (1 through 4) at a time.

```
setPartialMatch1(); // a-rhs.a
setPartialMatch2(); // b-rhs.b
setPartialMatch3(); // a-rhs.b
setPartialMatch4(); // b-rhs.a
```

I'd like to be able to enhance it so that in a single block I can identify the partially matching key.

```
setPartialMatch(); // magic
```

I've devised the unit test below. All of the partial matches using match 1 through match 4 work fine.  However, doing a partial match so that I don't need to do each one doesn't work.  You'll find that running this unit test will fail for all tests using setPartialMatch();

Any ideas or suggestions on how to get it to work, or alternatives would be great.

The full unit test is below:

```
/**
 * \file PartialMatchUnitTest.cpp
 *
 * \brief Unit testing for partial matching in std::map
 *
 * \author Otto Nahmee
 */

#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE PartialMatchingUnitTest

#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <map>

/*****************************************************************************/

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE(TestSuite)

/**
 * \class Identifier
 * \brief Used to identify and sort data in the map
 */
class Identifier
{
public:
    Identifier():
        idA(-1),
        idB(-1),
        partialMatch(false),
        partialMatch1(false),
        partialMatch2(false),
        partialMatch3(false),
        partialMatch4(false) {}

    Identifier(const long long int& a, const long long int& b):
        idA(a),
        idB(b),
        partialMatch(false),
        partialMatch1(false),
        partialMatch2(false),
        partialMatch3(false),
        partialMatch4(false) {}

    void setPartialMatch() { partialMatch = true; }
    void setPartialMatch1() { partialMatch1 = true; }
    void setPartialMatch2() { partialMatch2 = true; }
    void setPartialMatch3() { partialMatch3 = true; }
    void setPartialMatch4() { partialMatch4 = true; }

    bool operator==(const Identifier& rhs) const
    {
        return (idA == rhs.idA) && (idB == rhs.idB);
    }

    bool operator<(const Identifier& rhs) const
    {
        if (partialMatch || rhs.partialMatch)
        {
            // In order to match, only 1 should be false, the other 3 may or may not be false
            //
            // Note: The issue here is that the check that validates for the rhs.partialMatch should be identical
            //       to the check that validates for partialMatch. Since this is const that may not be possible
            if(rhs.partialMatch)
            {
                unsigned int check1 = (idA < rhs.idA) ? 1 : 0; // Match A to A
                unsigned int check2 = (idB < rhs.idB) ? 1 : 0; // Match B to B
                unsigned int check3 = (idA < rhs.idB) ? 1 : 0; // Match A to B
                unsigned int check4 = (idB < rhs.idA) ? 1 : 0; // Match B to A

                if( (check1 + check2 + check3 + check4) > 0 )
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else if(partialMatch)
            {
                unsigned int check1 = (idA < rhs.idA) ? 1 : 0; // Match A to A
                unsigned int check2 = (idB < rhs.idB) ? 1 : 0; // Match B to B
                unsigned int check3 = (idB < rhs.idA) ? 1 : 0; // Match B to A
                unsigned int check4 = (idA < rhs.idB) ? 1 : 0; // Match A to B

                if( (check1 + check2 + check3 + check4) > 0 )
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
        else if (partialMatch1 || rhs.partialMatch1)
        {
            // Match A to A
            if(rhs.partialMatch1)
            {
                if(idA < rhs.idA)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else if(partialMatch1)
            {
                if(idA < rhs.idA)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
        else if (partialMatch2 || rhs.partialMatch2)
        {
            // Match B to B
            if(rhs.partialMatch2)
            {
                if(idB < rhs.idB)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else if(partialMatch2)
            {
                if(idB < rhs.idB)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
        else if (partialMatch3 || rhs.partialMatch3)
        {
            // Match A to B
            if(rhs.partialMatch3)
            {
                if(idA < rhs.idB)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else if(partialMatch3)
            {
                if(idB < rhs.idA)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
        else if (partialMatch4 || rhs.partialMatch4)
        {
            // Match B to A
            if(rhs.partialMatch4)
            {
                if(idB < rhs.idA)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else if(partialMatch4)
            {
                if(idA < rhs.idB)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            if(idA < rhs.idA)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else if (idA == rhs.idA)
            {
                if(idB < rhs.idB)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

        }

        return false;
    }

private:
    long long int idA;
    long long int idB;

    bool partialMatch;
    bool partialMatch1;
    bool partialMatch2;
    bool partialMatch3;
    bool partialMatch4;
};

/**
 * \class Contents
 * \brief Contents to get merged in
 */
struct Contents
{
public:
    Contents():
        num1(0),
        num2(0),
        num3(0),
        num4(0)
    {}

    Contents(const long long int& n1, const long long int& n2, const long long int& n3, const long long int& n4):
        num1(n1),
        num2(n2),
        num3(n3),
        num4(n4)
    {}

    long long int num1;
    long long int num2;
    long long int num3;
    long long int num4;
};

typedef std::pair<Identifier, Contents> DataPair;
typedef std::map<Identifier, Contents> DataMap;



/**
 * \brief Testing Partial matching
 */
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(PartialMatch)
{
    DataMap dataMap;

    Identifier ID0(8, 9);
    dataMap[ID0] = Contents(1,2,3,4);

    Identifier ID1(10, 11);
    dataMap[ID1] = Contents(1,2,3,4);

    Identifier ID2(12, 14);
    dataMap[ID2] = Contents(1,2,3,4);

    Identifier ID3(15, 17);
    dataMap[ID3] = Contents(1,2,3,4);

    Identifier ID4(14, 22);
    dataMap[ID4] = Contents(1,2,3,4);

    Identifier ID5(23, 25);
    dataMap[ID5] = Contents(1,2,3,4);


    // Test perfect matching
    {
        Identifier perfectMatchID1(10, 11);

        DataMap::iterator it1 = dataMap.begin();
        it1 = dataMap.find(perfectMatchID1);
        BOOST_CHECK(it1 != dataMap.end());
        BOOST_CHECK(it1->first == ID1);


        Identifier perfectMatchID3(15, 17);

        DataMap::iterator it3 = dataMap.begin();
        it3 = dataMap.find(perfectMatchID3);
        BOOST_CHECK(it3 != dataMap.end());
        BOOST_CHECK(it3->first == ID3);
    }

    // Test partial matching
    // Try to match ID1 (10, 11);
    {
        Identifier partialMatchID1(10, 100);
        Identifier partialMatchID2(110, 11);
        Identifier partialMatchID3(110, 10);
        Identifier partialMatchID4(11, 100);

        Identifier partialMatchID5(10, 0);
        Identifier partialMatchID6(0, 11);
        Identifier partialMatchID7(0, 10);
        Identifier partialMatchID8(11, 0);

        Identifier partialMatchID9(10, 11);

        partialMatchID1.setPartialMatch1(); // a-rhs.a
        partialMatchID2.setPartialMatch2(); // b-rhs.b
        partialMatchID3.setPartialMatch3(); // a-rhs.b
        partialMatchID4.setPartialMatch4(); // b-rhs.a

        partialMatchID5.setPartialMatch1(); // a-rhs.a
        partialMatchID6.setPartialMatch2(); // b-rhs.b
        partialMatchID7.setPartialMatch3(); // a-rhs.b
        partialMatchID8.setPartialMatch4(); // b-rhs.a

        partialMatchID9.setPartialMatch1();

        DataMap::iterator it1 = dataMap.begin();
        it1 = dataMap.find(partialMatchID1);
        BOOST_CHECK(it1 != dataMap.end());
        BOOST_CHECK(it1->first == ID1);

        DataMap::iterator it2 = dataMap.begin();
        it2 = dataMap.find(partialMatchID2);
        BOOST_CHECK(it2 != dataMap.end());
        BOOST_CHECK(it2->first == ID1);

        DataMap::iterator it3 = dataMap.begin();
        it3 = dataMap.find(partialMatchID3);
        BOOST_CHECK(it3 != dataMap.end());
        BOOST_CHECK(it3->first == ID1);

        DataMap::iterator it4 = dataMap.begin();
        it4 = dataMap.find(partialMatchID4);
        BOOST_CHECK(it4 != dataMap.end());
        BOOST_CHECK(it4->first == ID1);

        DataMap::iterator it5 = dataMap.begin();
        it5 = dataMap.find(partialMatchID5);
        BOOST_CHECK(it5 != dataMap.end());
        BOOST_CHECK(it5->first == ID1);

        DataMap::iterator it6 = dataMap.begin();
        it6 = dataMap.find(partialMatchID6);
        BOOST_CHECK(it6 != dataMap.end());
        BOOST_CHECK(it6->first == ID1);

        DataMap::iterator it7 = dataMap.begin();
        it7 = dataMap.find(partialMatchID7);
        BOOST_CHECK(it7 != dataMap.end());
        BOOST_CHECK(it7->first == ID1);

        DataMap::iterator it8 = dataMap.begin();
        it8 = dataMap.find(partialMatchID8);
        BOOST_CHECK(it8 != dataMap.end());
        BOOST_CHECK(it8->first == ID1);

        DataMap::iterator it9 = dataMap.begin();
        it9 = dataMap.find(partialMatchID9);
        BOOST_CHECK(it9 != dataMap.end());
        BOOST_CHECK(it9->first == ID1);
    }

    // Try to match ID1 (10, 11);
    {
        Identifier partialMatchID1(10, 100);
        Identifier partialMatchID2(110, 11);
        Identifier partialMatchID3(11, 100);
        Identifier partialMatchID4(110, 10);

        Identifier partialMatchID5(10, 0);
        Identifier partialMatchID6(0, 11);
        Identifier partialMatchID7(11, 0);
        Identifier partialMatchID8(0, 10);

        Identifier partialMatchID9(10, 11);

        partialMatchID1.setPartialMatch();
        partialMatchID2.setPartialMatch();
        partialMatchID3.setPartialMatch();
        partialMatchID4.setPartialMatch();

        partialMatchID5.setPartialMatch();
        partialMatchID6.setPartialMatch();
        partialMatchID7.setPartialMatch();
        partialMatchID8.setPartialMatch();

        partialMatchID9.setPartialMatch();

        DataMap::iterator it1 = dataMap.begin();
        it1 = dataMap.find(partialMatchID1);
        BOOST_CHECK(it1 != dataMap.end());
        BOOST_CHECK(it1->first == ID1);

        DataMap::iterator it2 = dataMap.begin();
        it2 = dataMap.find(partialMatchID2);
        BOOST_CHECK(it2 != dataMap.end());
        BOOST_CHECK(it2->first == ID1);

        DataMap::iterator it3 = dataMap.begin();
        it3 = dataMap.find(partialMatchID3);
        BOOST_CHECK(it3 != dataMap.end());
        BOOST_CHECK(it3->first == ID1);

        DataMap::iterator it4 = dataMap.begin();
        it4 = dataMap.find(partialMatchID4);
        BOOST_CHECK(it4 != dataMap.end());
        BOOST_CHECK(it4->first == ID1);

        DataMap::iterator it5 = dataMap.begin();
        it5 = dataMap.find(partialMatchID5);
        BOOST_CHECK(it5 != dataMap.end());
        BOOST_CHECK(it5->first == ID1);

        DataMap::iterator it6 = dataMap.begin();
        it6 = dataMap.find(partialMatchID6);
        BOOST_CHECK(it6 != dataMap.end());
        BOOST_CHECK(it6->first == ID1);

        DataMap::iterator it7 = dataMap.begin();
        it7 = dataMap.find(partialMatchID7);
        BOOST_CHECK(it7 != dataMap.end());
        BOOST_CHECK(it7->first == ID1);

        DataMap::iterator it8 = dataMap.begin();
        it8 = dataMap.find(partialMatchID8);
        BOOST_CHECK(it8 != dataMap.end());
        BOOST_CHECK(it8->first == ID1);

        DataMap::iterator it9 = dataMap.begin();
        it9 = dataMap.find(partialMatchID9);
        BOOST_CHECK(it9 != dataMap.end());
        BOOST_CHECK(it9->first == ID1);
    }


    // Try to match ID3 (15, 17);
    {
        Identifier partialMatchID1(15, 100);
        Identifier partialMatchID2(110, 17);
        Identifier partialMatchID3(17, 100);
        Identifier partialMatchID4(110, 15);

        Identifier partialMatchID5(15, 0);
        Identifier partialMatchID6(0, 17);
        Identifier partialMatchID7(17, 0);
        Identifier partialMatchID8(0, 15);

        Identifier partialMatchID9(15, 17);

        partialMatchID1.setPartialMatch();
        partialMatchID2.setPartialMatch();
        partialMatchID3.setPartialMatch();
        partialMatchID4.setPartialMatch();

        partialMatchID5.setPartialMatch();
        partialMatchID6.setPartialMatch();
        partialMatchID7.setPartialMatch();
        partialMatchID8.setPartialMatch();

        partialMatchID9.setPartialMatch();


        DataMap::iterator it1 = dataMap.begin();
        it1 = dataMap.find(partialMatchID1);
        BOOST_CHECK(it1 != dataMap.end());
        BOOST_CHECK(it1->first == ID3);

        DataMap::iterator it2 = dataMap.begin();
        it2 = dataMap.find(partialMatchID2);
        BOOST_CHECK(it2 != dataMap.end());
        BOOST_CHECK(it2->first == ID3);

        DataMap::iterator it3 = dataMap.begin();
        it3 = dataMap.find(partialMatchID3);
        BOOST_CHECK(it3 != dataMap.end());
        BOOST_CHECK(it3->first == ID3);

        DataMap::iterator it4 = dataMap.begin();
        it4 = dataMap.find(partialMatchID4);
        BOOST_CHECK(it4 != dataMap.end());
        BOOST_CHECK(it4->first == ID3);

        DataMap::iterator it5 = dataMap.begin();
        it5 = dataMap.find(partialMatchID5);
        BOOST_CHECK(it5 != dataMap.end());
        BOOST_CHECK(it5->first == ID3);

        DataMap::iterator it6 = dataMap.begin();
        it6 = dataMap.find(partialMatchID6);
        BOOST_CHECK(it6 != dataMap.end());
        BOOST_CHECK(it6->first == ID3);

        DataMap::iterator it7 = dataMap.begin();
        it7 = dataMap.find(partialMatchID7);
        BOOST_CHECK(it7 != dataMap.end());
        BOOST_CHECK(it7->first == ID3);

        DataMap::iterator it8 = dataMap.begin();
        it8 = dataMap.find(partialMatchID8);
        BOOST_CHECK(it8 != dataMap.end());
        BOOST_CHECK(it8->first == ID3);

        DataMap::iterator it9 = dataMap.begin();
        it9 = dataMap.find(partialMatchID9);
        BOOST_CHECK(it9 != dataMap.end());
        BOOST_CHECK(it9->first == ID3);
    }


}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()

/*****************************************************************************/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't with a `std::map`. It answers to [strict-weak-ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293231/stl-ordering-strict-weak-ordering) The exception happens here in the map's comparator:

```
{   // test if _Pred(_Left, _Right) and _Pred is strict weak ordering
return (!_Pred(_Left, _Right)
    ? false
    : _Pred(_Right, _Left)
        ? (_DEBUG_ERROR2("invalid comparator", _File, _Line), true)
        : true);
```

As well as I'm not sure what you are doing here:

```
Identifier partialMatchID(3, 2);
partialMatchID.setPartialMatch1();
std::map<SimpleIdentifier, Contents>::iterator it = dataMap.begin();
it = dataMap.find(partialMatchID);
```

> This is nice because I can go through
>   each iterator in a while loop to find every matching key-value pair
>   and do something with it.

`map.find` will return only one unique match. If you are 'iterating' it must be beyond `map.find`. You can not do what you are trying to do with `std::map`, at least from what I understand.

Because you want to match on different ordering, I don't see any way but to use another indexing container, or, boost::multi_index, or, just do a linear search for the 'other' ordering.

Comment: "map.find will return only one unique match. If you are 'iterating' it must be beyond map.find" -- It returns only one unique match. If I put std::find in a while loop then I can find all matching key-value pairs until no more match.