# `std::nth_element` fails for `std::less_equal` and `std::greater_equal` predicate

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, std

I just got a **segmentation fault** from both GCC 9.1 and clang 8.0 when using `std::nth_element` with the custom predicates `std::less_equal` or `std::greater_equal`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::vector<int> vals{1, 2, 5, 1, 3, 2, 1};

  std::nth_element(begin(vals), begin(vals)+2, end(vals), std::greater_equal{});

  copy(cbegin(vals), cend(vals), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

In contrast, everything works as expected when using `std::less` or `std::greater`.

I believe that I understand the reason behind it: as an optimization, *unguarded* loops (without bounds checking) are used internally under the assumption that the predicate returns `false` for equal elements. I am just surprised that I can not find that requirement in the documentation.

Here is what I find in [N4659](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf):

> ```
> // [...]
>
> template<class RandomAccessIterator, class Compare>
> void nth_element(RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator nth,
> RandomAccessIterator last, Compare comp);
>
> // [...]
> ```
>
> 1. *Requires:* `RandomAccessIterator` shall satisfy the requirements of
>      `ValueSwappable` (20.5.3.2). The type of `*first` shall satisfy the
>      requirements of `MoveConstructible` (Table 23) and of `MoveAssignable`
>      (Table 25).
> 2. *Effects:* After `nth_element` the element in the position
>      pointed to by `nth` is the element that would be in that position if
>      the whole range were sorted, unless `nth == last`. Also for every
>      iterator `i` in the range `[first, nth)` and every iterator `j` in the
>      range `[nth, last)` it holds that: `!(*j < *i)` or 
>      `comp(*j, *i) == false`.
> 3. *Complexity:* [...].

From the above, I can not infer the requirement that the predicate must return `false` for equal elements.

Here is a quote from [cppreference.com on `std::nth_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element):

> ```
> // [...]
>
> template< class RandomIt, class Compare >
> void nth_element( RandomIt first, RandomIt nth, RandomIt last,
>                   Compare comp );                   // (until C++20)
>
> // [...]
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> comp - comparison function object (i.e. an object that satisfies the
>   requirements of *Compare*) which returns ​`true` if the first argument
>   is *less* than (i.e. is ordered *before*) the second. [...]

Although the two words *less* and *before* are displayed with italic font, I feel like there could be a more explicit hint.

**Here are my questions:**

1. Am I correct that the predicate has to return `false` for equal elements?
2. Am I missing some important statement from the standard that explicitly documents this requirement?
3. Depending on answers on the above: is there anything to do on this issue (read more parts of the standard, defect report, bug report, or improve cppreference.com documentation)?

Comment: If the first argument is equal to the second, it isn't _less than_ the second. I don't believe that's ambiguous.

Comment: Possible duplicate or at least very much related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1293231/5910058

Comment: @JesperJuhl: Thank you, that made me find it [28.7(3) of N4659](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf#section.28.7): "[...] For algorithms other than those described in 28.7.3, `comp` shall
induce a strict weak ordering on the values."