# std::is_sorted return false when lambda return always true

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, lambda, comparison

Please explain why this code is crashing?

```
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> vt = {1,2,3,4};
    assert(std::is_sorted(vt.begin(), vt.end(), [](const auto& a, const auto& b){ return true;}));
}
```

[https://godbolt.org/](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:10,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:10,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:10,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:10),source:%27%0A%23include+%3Cvector%3E%0A%23include+%3Ccassert%3E%0A%23include+%3Calgorithm%3E%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++std::vector%3Cint%3E+vt+%3D+%7B1,2,3,4%7D%3B%0A++++assert(std::is_sorted(vt.begin(),+vt.end(),+%5B%5D(const+auto%26+a,+const+auto%26+b)%7B+return+true%3B%7D))%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:45.65537555228278,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:executor,i:(argsPanelShown:%271%27,compilationPanelShown:%270%27,compiler:clang170assert,compilerName:%27%27,compilerOutShown:%270%27,execArgs:%27%27,execStdin:%27%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B17+-Wall%27,overrides:!(),runtimeTools:!(),source:1,stdinPanelShown:%271%27,tree:%271%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Executor+x86-64+clang+17.0.1+(assertions)+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:54.34462444771725,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

Comment: Your comparator is invalid. It does not meet [the requirements of a comparer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare), specifically it does not meet the anticommutative or reflexivity requirements.

Comment: Because the predicate must establish a strict weak ordering, just like for `std::sort`. Your predicate says "every element is ordered before every element, including itself".

Comment: Neat little tidbit, libstdc++ detects this when turning on debug mode: https://godbolt.org/z/ahrsv48cd. Someone recently gave a talk about improving libc++ support for this as well.

Comment: [Why will std::sort crash if the comparison function is not as operator <?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18291620/why-will-stdsort-crash-if-the-comparison-function-is-not-as-operator) and [Why does the standard library require a strict weak ordering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293231/why-does-the-standard-library-require-a-strict-weak-ordering)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The comparison function (the lambda expression) is incorrect. It returns always `true` for `vt[i] < vt[j]` and for `vt[j] < vt[i]`. As a result the call of the algorithm has undefined behavior.

From  the C++ Standard:

> For algorithms other than those described in 25.4.3 to work correctly,
> **comp has to induce a strict weak ordering on the values**.

For example the algorithm can be implemented the following way

```
template<class ForwardIterator, class Compare>
bool is_sorted( ForwardIterator first,
    ForwardIterator last,
    Compare comp )
{
    if (first != last)
    {

        for (auto prev = first; ++first != last && !comp( *first, *prev );)
        {
            ++prev;
        }
    }

    return first == last;
}
```

As you can see the expression `!comp( *first, *prev )` will at once return false for a sorted sequence.

Answer (score 4):

This is true that your compare function doesn't meet requirements, but it doesn't mean this is reason of your code crashing. Standard library is not obligated to verify this (and in this case, for this algorithm, it doesn't do that).

Your code is not crashing it is aborting since this is how [`assert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert) works when condition is not met. Simply `std::is_sorted(vt.begin(), vt.end(), [](const auto& a, const auto& b){ return true;})` is evaluated to `false` and assert is triggered.

[Demo with true](https://godbolt.org/z/YGPq93cnE)

[Demo with false](https://godbolt.org/z/v5xoPnW63)

Note what documentation says:

[std::is_sorted - cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_sorted)

> A sequence is sorted with respect to a comparator `comp` if for any iterator `it` pointing to the sequence and any non-negative integer `n` such that `it + n` is a valid iterator pointing to an element of the sequence, `comp(*(it + n), *it)` evaluates to **false**.

Note that `comp` gets arguments in reversed order, so if items are sorted `comp` must always return `false`! Rationale of such design of algorithm is that range containing consecutive repeating values should be considered as sorted too. So for example `{1, 1, 2, 2}` is sorted when operator `<` (less) is used by default.